# Calculate partial time elapsed between two times

Tags: php

I have an interface written in PHP that documents employees time worked. I'd like to add a new algorithm that measures the amount of time worked between certain hours for the purpose of calculating shift differentials. I'm using MySQL's `unix_time()` for the timestamps.

Example: Employee works from 6PM until 2AM. There is a paid shift differential between 10PM and 6AM. Employee receives regular pay for 4 hours and their pay + differential for 4 hours.

```
$start_time = 1459015200; // 18:00 03/26/2016
$end_time = 1459044000; // 02:00 03/27/2016

$diff_start = mktime('22','00','00','3','26','2016');
$diff_end = mktime('06','00','00','3','27','2016');
```

I'd like to write a script that calculates the amount of time worked between 10PM and 6PM, given a large set of possibilities of times worked. This answer accomplishes appears to do what I'm looking for, except in MySQL: [Calculating time difference before 6am and after 10pm in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345607/calculating-time-difference-before-6am-and-after-10pm-in-mysql)

This answer is similar to my problem: [Calculate the number of hours in a given timeframe between two datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986011/calculate-the-number-of-hours-in-a-given-timeframe-between-two-datetimes) but relies on a loop. Given that times are entered in seconds based on `unix_time`, I would presume to use a loop would require a one second increment (which means a lot of passes through the loop for thousands of records per week).

Is there an efficient way (such as the MySQL example) to do this in PHP that doesn't require looping every incremental second/minute/hour as suggested in the second answer?

Comment: 22-18 + 6-2? Start of differential minus start of shift, plus end of differential minus end of shift? Maybe I'm not following.

Comment: Shifting during dst switch! Fateful time choice.

Comment: You're not kidding. Maybe one day I'll take the time to convert to a different format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is: Use Arrays with specially formed keys. First of all

```
mktime('22','00','00','3','26','2016') => 1459026000
mktime('06','00','00','3','27','2016') => 1459051200
```

Now build your differential array:

```
$shifts=array (
  0 => 0,
  1459026000 => $diff,
  1459051200 => 0
);
```

This means, that from timestamp 0..1459025999 the differential is 0, from 1459026000 to 1459051199 the differential is `$diff` and from 1459051200 to infinity it is 0 again. Ofcourse your real shift table will be much larger.

You now run through this array exactly once with soemthing like `foreach ($shifts as $start=>$differential)` and compare `$start` to `$start_time` and `$end_time`, with these cases:

- `$start>$end_time`: ignore, this is in the future
- `$start<$start_time`: ignore, this is in the past
- else: calculate number of seconds and use $differential

Comment: This is not going to work when you have an iteration with $diff=1 and $start < $start_time, as you don't know if $nextStart > $start_time

Comment: @Jack - 1. the value of `$diff` is of no importance for the time calculation - it could be -3.1415 without changing the algorithm; 2. While i don't know anything about the **next** start, I do know everything about the **previous** start, which is the rationale for the first line of the array (`0 => 0`), so I handle this case in the next, not in the previous iteration on the 'else' branch.

Comment: I don't get the algorithm. Suppose you have $start_time = 1459029600 (11:00PM) and $end_time = 1459036800 (01:00AM). All of your iterations should be ignored according to the cases you stated.

Comment: Also, suppose you have 09:00PM ~ 01:00AM. Your second iteration is 1459026000 > $start_time and 1459026000 < $end_time.. Good. Now what you do? How do you identify you have to apply differential for 3 hours?

Comment: @Jack - it's easy: You remember the start time and differential. When the next iteration starts, you see, that 1 h has passed and apply this differential for one hour. You then continue with the increased new start time, which happens to be the same start time as the shift, 10 p.m.. On the next iteration (6 a.m.) you now know, you have to use the last differential from 10 p.m. to 1 a.m.

Comment: Aah ok, now I see it. Kind of inefficient for a large shift table, but fine. Thanks

Comment: @Jack The inefficiency goes away,if you keep the past part of the shift table short - the future part is of no importance, as you can leave the loop, once you are completely in the future.

Comment: I think the smart part of the question is to find efficiently the closest past and the closest future. If you do so, you don't even need a loop and the computation is trivial.

Comment: The closest past can quite simply be found by binary search over the keys of the shift array. The closest future is reached as an exit condition, once we hit the first bullet in the algorithm.

Comment: You don't need the binary search. You can find it in constant time. Also, you probably don't need to work with unix-time, but it's more efficient to only consider Time instead of DateTime

Comment: Jack, the UNIX-timestamps are a requirement from the OQ. You are welcome to show us a better, easier, faster or more efficient algorithm - I'll upvote it.

Comment: Wait.. Requirement is "efficient with no loops". Since differential starts at 10PM no matter the day, and ends at 06AM no matter the day, I just say it's more efficient to evaluate just the time. Moreover, I actually already posted a hint of solution, which is more efficient then yours but very complex. Probably caring only about hours:minute is the best choice.

Comment: Jack, your proposal hinges on a fictional function, that does the heavy lifting - you provide no hints at all, as how it should work. In addition to that, shifts are not the same every day - think of weekends, holidays, etc. So unless you have anything constructive to contribute, I consider this discussion closed.

Answer (score 0):

Loved this question. Looked like an interview question. I spent some time to implement this efficiently with no loops. First of all I implemented the following:

```
function date_intersection($a_from, $a_to, $b_from, $b_to);
```

returning the seconds in between two time ranges.

Then, with the constraint that a shift can't be longer than 24 hours, I needed to build two range blocks:

- the range with differential which is before your current time shift
- the range with differential which is after

After it, solution is straightforward:

```
$total = $end_time - $start_time;
$differ = date_intersection($b1s, $b1e, $start_time, $end_time) + date_intersection($b2s, $b2e, $start_time, $end_time);
$normal = $total-$differ;
```

Efficiently solve this question involve not using mktime() or date() to extract part of your date, as you really can solve the problem with module operator over unix-timestamp. But taking care of DST really made it complex.
If you only had not asked this question tonight I would have answer before (incorrectly) :)

Comment: I appreciate the followup post. I'm not sure I understand the point of your `date_intersection` function. Did something get cut out? Also, what is the purpose of $b1s/e & $b2s/e?

Comment: I thought there were no constraints on what time differential starts/ends, and on what time work shift starts/ends. If you have the latter, problem is trivial, as you can pre-compute differentials for all possible shifts.(date_intersection(10, 15, 12, 22) == 3) and (b1s = block_1_start).